# ngOnInit() when called from another component does not refresh the component

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, ngoninit

Am having two components named AddPersons and PersonList. After adding a person in the AddPerson component, I am trying to refresh the PersonList component. For that I tried calling the ngOnInit() of PersonList component from AddPerson.

I am getting the updated data in PersonList but the list is not getting updated in html.

add-person-component.ts:

```
constructor(private personService: PersonService, private compPersonList: PersonListComponent, ) { }



onAddPerson(): void {

var modalContainer = "#add-person";

this.personService
  .addPersons(this.name, this.age)
  .subscribe(
    response => {
      if (response === true) {
        this.compPersonList.ngOnInit();
        $(modalContainer).modal('hide');

      }
    },
    error => {
      this.errorDetails = this.errorHandlingService.getErrorModel(error);
    });
}
```

person-list-component.ts:

```
ngOnInit(): void
{
  this.populateGrid();
}
```

Comment: fiiiirst of all, in no case ever do you call `OnInit` manually. Secondly, check component interaction: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#component-interaction

Answer (score 0):

1. there is syntax error at end of your controller.
   Unexpected ','
2. instead of calling another page component through onOnit() try

"**this.router.navigate(['URL','Params']);**"